# Changes to variable array elements (variable parameter) not visible outside of procedure

Tags: delphi, pass-by-reference

I am trying to implement procedure taking variable number of parameters using variable arrays.
Issue is that changes to passed variables are not visible outside of the procedure.

```
procedure arrChange(var arr: array of String);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to Length(arr) do
    arr[0] := 'changed';
end;

procedure strChange(var str: String);
begin
  str := 'changed';
end;

procedure strChangeNotVariable(str: String);
begin
  str := 'changed again';
end;

var a, b: String;
begin
  a := 'a';  
  b := 'b';

  print(a); // prints a - expected   
  print(b); // prints b - expected  

  arrChange ([a, b]);

  print(a); // prints a  - why?
  print(b); // prints b  - why? 

  strChange(a);     
  strChange(b);

  print(a); // prints changed - expected 
  print(b); // prints changed - expected

  strChangeNotVariable(a);
  strChangeNotVariable(b); 

  print(a); // prints changed - expected 
  print(b); // prints changed - expected
end.
```

Can I get some explanation on why are changes outside of arrChange not visible and/or possible way how to solve it?

Comment: You might want to look at this article if you haven't already:http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html,  FWIW, the upper bound of your `for` loop in `arrChange` is one too high, because open array arguments are zero-based.

Comment: You are passing a constant array into a var parameter. Gives a compiler error on newer Delphi versions.

Comment: @MartynA: Thanks for plugging my site. <g>

Comment: FWIW, please, next time, post a [MCVE]. The code above does not compile, as it is not a complete program, and e.g. `print()` is missing.

Comment: @Rudy:  My pleasure, it is a very valuable resource imo.

Comment: @MartynA: <blushing>

Comment: @bistabil. I'm not able to compile your code. Please state your Delphi version and make a compilable example.

Comment: @MartynA: FWIW, the upper limit of the loop could just as well be `1000000`, since he is modifying `arr[0]` only. It would just take a little longer, but no range error.<g>

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Indeed, I did not provide implementation of print but that's not the point there. Point is that update is not visible outside. You can as well imagine that there is no print at all.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis:  Just as well you're answering him then, not me  <g>

Comment: @bistabl: to make people follow your point, if possible, you should post a [MCVE]. Then people can compile your code and check what is happening. If people must invent large parts of the code themselves, thy might consider it not worth the trouble and simply ignore your question. In other words: if you want people to answer your questions, it is always best to make it easy for others to check your code and give a meaningful answer.

Comment: Code snippet I put here contains a problem with upper value counter will get. This was a mistake I made while trying to illustrate main issue.

Comment: @bistabil:  I think you may be overlooking Rudy's point about the effect on other readers.  You are, after all, asking people to help f.o.c

Comment: What should be the next step then? Do you suggest rewriting original code and updating the question with compilable example?

Comment: @bistabil, at least your code example should point out your problem correctly. Right now it does not make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should know this about *open array parameters*: there is something called an *open array constructor*. This is what happens if you don't pass a real existing array to such an *open array parameter*, but a bunch of values enclosed in square brackets, like you did.

For such *open array constructors*, the compiler writes code that creates an ad hoc array **on the stack** (it reserves stack space and then puts the values in there) and then passes a pointer to that ad hoc array and its size minus one to the procedure. Such ad hoc arrays are only valid as long as the procedure runs, i.e. only **inside the procedure**. They disappear when the procedure exits. That is why they can't be passed as `var` (reference) parameters. Some versions did perhaps allow it, but that would simply change the copies on the stack, not the originals.

If you want your trick to work, you must pass a real existing array. That can be something like:

```
var
  d: array of string;
...
  SetLength(d, 2);
  d[0] := a;
  d[1] := b;
  arrChange(d);
```

Now, if you print `d[0]` and `d[1]` after the procedure, they should show `'changed'`. But `a` and `b` should still be intact and not be changed, because `d` only contains copies.

It does affect `a` and `b` directly only if you pass an `array of PString`. But then there is still no need to make the open array a reference parameter. I tried this:

```
procedure arrChange(const arr: array of PString);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to High(arr) do
    // Not modifying arr[i] itself, only to what it points!
    arr[i]^ := 'changed'; // FWIW, you had arr[0] instead of arr[i] ;-)
end;
```

and

```
arrChange([@a, @b]);
print(a);
print(b);
```

That worked and produced

```
changed
changed
```

with

```
procedure print(const s: string);
begin
  Writeln(s);
end;
```

More info: [Open array parameters and array of const](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html).

---

*FWIW, it seems that the compiler does not even update the reference count for the strings. It puts a raw copy of the pointer on the stack, like it would for a `const` string*.

Comment: Although I did not provide real example I am working on (I've tried to isolate important part) you got the point and gave great answer.